# Super simple if+elif+else statement not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

This section is from How to automate the boring stuff chapter 2. I don't understand why this doesn't work, please help.

```
spam=input()
if spam == 1:
    print('Hello')
elif spam == 2:
    print('Howdy')
else:
    print('Greetings!')
```

There is no error, but whatever I put, python gives me Greetings! and if I take off the else part, nothing happens. I'm a beginner sorry if it's a stupid question

Comment: `input()` returns `str` not `int`. Try `spam = int(input())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

convert spam to int

```
spam = int(spam)
```